# Sometimes CKEditor doesn't display all buttons in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I have a Rails app that uses CKEditor. Sometimes the text editor doesn't display all the buttons (the Source, add picture, etc buttons are missing):

[image]

However, sometimes it does, or it does if I refresh enough times:

[image]

I haven't detected a pattern to when or when it doesn't display all the buttons. Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: Are those on the same page and the same text field? Or, are they on different pages and different text fields?

Comment: @Uzbekjon: those are on the same page and same text field. If a specific CKeditor in a particular location is missing buttons, it'll eventually work if I reload the page enough times.